# Open URL commands in a batch file causing problems with my URL link being opened

Tags: command-line, firefox, batch, url

I have a rather peculiar issue. When I run a batch script to open a URL, all of the commands I have tried **removes** the characters %3 from my URL when sending the URL to the browser. Because of this, the URL does not open properly. Does anyone have any ideas?

I've tried start, rundll32, url.dll, FileProtocolHandler, etc., etc., etc., and none of them work. I even tried putting the link in quotations which did not work.

**Original link example:**
https://service-now.com/sc_req_item_list.do?sysparm_query=active%3Dtrue^assignment_group%3Dddd73dd34070240048b6bd9617591f4e^ORassignment_group%3Df5c1bd534070240048b6bd9617591fbe^GOTOrequest.requested_for.location.nameLIKEUS%20%28^request.requested_for.location.nameNOT%20LIKEHouston^assigned_toISEMPTY^u_product_name!%3DNetwork%20and%20Email%20account%20-%20modified^u_product_name!%3DNetwork%20and%20Email%20account^u_product_name!%3DRe-enable%20user%20account^u_product_name!%3DAccount%20termination^u_product_name!%3DLync%20Instant%20Messaging&sysparm_first_row=1&sysparm_view="

**Link Opened after running it from a batch file:**
https://service-now.com/sc_req_item_list.do?sysparm_query=activeDtrue^assignment_groupDddd73dd34070240048b6bd9617591f4e^ORassignment_groupDf5c1bd534070240048b6bd9617591fbe^GOTOrequest.requested_for.location.nameLIKEUS08^request.requested_for.location.nameNOT0LIKEHouston^assigned_toISEMPTY^u_product_name!DNetwork0and0Email0account0-0modified^u_product_name!DNetwork0and0Email0account^u_product_name!DRe-enable0user0account^u_product_name!DAccount0termination^u_product_name!DLync0Instant0Messaging&sysparm_first_row=1&sysparm_view=

Using the open commands in the command prompt window does work, however, just not from a batch file?

Comment: Your original link example is broken as it does not work when pasted into the firefox address bar.

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill, thank you for trying to help me. I removed some things from the URL due to being for a company page and not meant for public access. Either way if you try out a batch script like with the following:

rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler "[original link here]"

Then you will see how the string of %3 gets removed at the hand over of the URL.

Thanks!

EDIT: Ok wow... I just noticed that the browser won't show the URL due to my modifications. Let me see please.

Comment: Without having a real URL to test I will just make a comment. Your URL includes a lot of characters that have other meanings in a batch file, including `%`, `^`, `&`, and `!`. You may need to [escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) some or all of these.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I did figure out how to get the browser to show the url, but feel a response to your statement would be more helpful for me. I totally agree with you but I thought by adding quotations that it would open the url exactly as typed?

Comment: If you add quotes it is no longer a URL ... for example `start www.google.com` works, but `start "www.google.com"` fails as the first parameter to `start` that is quoted is assumed to be the title of a `cmd` window.

Comment: AH! Makes sense to me now. I will research how to use escape characters. Though strange that it works when I try it through command prompt directly! XD

Thanks!

Comment: Good luck. Escaping in batch files is messy ... especially if you want to modify the URL on the fly ...

Comment: Do you have a recommended command that I could use for url's?

I found some other threads similar to mine now :).

Comment: Just use `start` and get the escaping right :)

Comment: In my URL I just needed to replace %3 with ^%3, and also remove quotes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails you may want to try using a url shortener to get a simpler url to use... assuming it's a static address or you can automate your own shortening process.